# Azure CosmosDB - incremental backups

Tags: azure

Considering the young age of CosmosDB .

1. Are there any way to perform Incremental backups ?
2. Are there any tools than can help validating the integrity of a backup?

Something that traditional enterprise RDBMS are providing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any way to perform Incremental backups?

There are no other ways of managing external backups for cosmos DB as we are still awaiting the update on this.

Are there any tools than can help validate the integrity of a backup?

Not sure of online DB backups, but you can take backups through dump path using any cloud based backup software like cloudberry with azure servers.

The dump files need to be restored on the servers and the loaded into the DB server.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation for Azure CosmosDB online backup and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore)

As per the documentation, backup and restore for CosmosDB is 'limited' to full backup every 4 hours, with snapshots kept for 30 days (in geo-redundant blob storage). If you need more than that, you have to schedule additional backups and exports manually (using the data migration tool).

However, [a comment from 'govind@MSFT' on the azure feedback platform](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6331712-backup-solution-for-documentdb) claims that  backups are now taken continuously.

For restore, you still need to open a support ticket.

I suspect this will evolve to something similar to Azure SQL (there you get weekly full backup, differential backup every few hours, tx log backup every few minutes + self service point in time restore), but they're not quite there yet, or so it seems.

Comment: I am quite familiar with official manual/docs. My question is how much can I go away from pout of the box solution. are there any commercial/OS tools that will complement Cosmos DB ?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to maintain your own snapshots, you can use the export to JSON option in the Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration tool to schedule additional backups.

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore

Comment: "If you accidentally delete your database or collection, you can file a support ticket or call Azure support"